# how to use Zxing with DecoratedBarcodeView and CaptureManager to scan only QR code?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I call the following function to start scanning the QR code from my `Activity` which has a `DecoratedBarcodeView` in its layout.

```
private void openBackCamera() {
        captureManager = new CaptureManager(this, decoratedBarcodeView);
        captureManager.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
        captureManager.decode();

        CameraSettings cameraSettings = decoratedBarcodeView.getBarcodeView().getCameraSettings();
        cameraSettings.setAutoFocusEnabled(false);
        cameraSettings.setFocusMode(CameraSettings.FocusMode.CONTINUOUS);
        cameraSettings.setRequestedCameraId(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);

        decoratedBarcodeView.pause();
        decoratedBarcodeView.getBarcodeView().setFrameRectColor(Color.WHITE);
        decoratedBarcodeView.getBarcodeView().setFramingRectSize(getSize());
        decoratedBarcodeView.getViewFinder().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        decoratedBarcodeView.decodeSingle(mBarcodeResult);
        decoratedBarcodeView.resume();
    }
```

by default, it scans all kind of barcodes and I want to limit it to QR codes.

I tried adding following lines to launch intent so they can be used by `captureManager` when I initialize it with `getIntent()` with no avail.

```
        intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.MODE, Intents.Scan.QR_CODE_MODE);
        intent.putExtra(Intents.Scan.FORMATS, "QR_CODE");
```

How can I limit my setup to scan only QR codes?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer when you're working only with `DecoratedBarcodeView`:

```
List<BarcodeFormat> formats = new ArrayList<>();
formats.add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
decoratedBarcodeView.getBarcodeView().setDecoderFactory(new DefaultDecoderFactory(formats));
```

You then don't need to work with `Intent` and `CaptureManager`.

Answer (score 0):

used `IntentIntegrator` to generate launch intent with QR code formats instead of directly setting intent extras in launch intent.

```
   public static Intent getLaunchIntent(Activity activity) {
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
        integrator.setCaptureActivity(QrCodeScanActivity.class);
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
        return integrator.createScanIntent();
    }
```

there were no clear examples available. hope this will help someone.